# Text falling below image

Tags: html, css, image

[image: Good]
[image: Bad]

I need this text to wrap, but I don't understand why it isn't. If it gets to long, it simply falls below the image.

```
<style>
.discussion {
width: 50%;
min-height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.discussion img {
margin: 12.5px;
float: left;
}
.discussion a {
text-decoration: none;
margin-top: 12.5px;
display:inline-block;
}
#discussion_title {
font-size: 22px;
color: #3f3f3f;
margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
<div class="discussion">
<img src="http://images.elephantjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/mirror_cat-500x500.jpg" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="discussion_text">
    <a href="view-topic.php?tid=" id="discussion_title"> blah blah blah</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDuAB/)

Comment: `.discussion {` 
   ` ....`
   ` display : inline; // add this`
   ` } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CsDam)

Remove `display: inline-block` of `.discussion a` and add

```
.discussion_text {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I remove the inline-block, I get this problem where the text is next to the name instead of below it: http://prntscr.com/42hrug

Comment: I guess you are using <a> for the name which is inline element. You can give display block to it or wrap it in a div. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CsDam) is the example with giving display block to name.

Comment: Thank you again. It'll probably help if I give you the rest of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/AL3fj/ As you can see, when I do it like that, the alignment of the name and time get pushed out of place despite having the same margin.

Comment: You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AL3fj/1/). I have changed display to inline-block for #discussion_name and added .clear div after #discussion_time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.discussion img {
    margin: 12.5px;
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    width:10%; /* Whatever it should be*/
}
.discussion a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 12.5px;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @spex: what do you mean by this link.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `float:left` too on the `discussion_text` and make it have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the `.discussion a { display: inline-block; }`, so you can either remove that or change it to `.discussion a { display: block; }` for text to flow around the image nicely, article-style.

http://jsfiddle.net/9aMxg/2/

Or you can add the following for `discussion_text` not to wrap, but it will stay in a column, not flow around the image:

```
.discussion_text {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MfadJ/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `inline` for `a`, that way, you will not be able to customize it any further as `inline` elements can not be *styled* easily and in very limited manner!

`inline-block` will make `a` only equal to width of the content .

Just amend this part and all is good

```
.discussion a {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-top: 12.5px;
        display:block; //changed from inline-block
    }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDuAB/2/)

Also, you have used excess CSS to achieve your target, it can be trimmed down!